# Docker registry mirror not saving images with minikube

Tags: docker, minikube

I am trying to setup a docker registry mirror using the steps [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/) and [here](https://blog.docker.com/2015/10/registry-proxy-cache-docker-open-source/)

The command I use to start the registry mirror is

```
docker run -d --restart=always -p 5000:5000 --name registry-mirror -v /Users/proxycache/docker-proxy-cache/data:/var/lib/registry -v /Users/proxycache/docker-proxy-cache/config:/etc/docker/registry registry:2
```

my config looks like

```
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
  delete:
    enabled: true
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
proxy:
  remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
```

I did not setup any certs because this is just local and not tied to a domain.

after it starts I am able to run `curl -I http://proxycache.local:5000/v2/` and I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 17:52:21 GMT
```

I can also run `curl http://proxycache.local:5000/v2/_catalog` and I get

```
{"repositories":[]}
```

I then start minikube with this command `minikube start --vm-driver=xhyve --disk-size=40g --memory=8192 --registry-mirror http://proxycache.local:5000 --insecure-registry http://proxycache.local:5000`

`eval $(minikube docker-env)`

If I run `docker info` I get

```
Containers: 59
 Running: 22
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 37
Images: 15
Server Version: 1.11.1
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Swarm: 
 NodeID: 
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 
Init Binary: 
containerd version: 
runc version: 
init version: 
Kernel Version: 4.7.2
Operating System: Buildroot 2016.08
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.797 GiB
Name: minikube
ID: JGCU:HKNT:AOEL:PRNQ:DRNE:OQAM:2PI2:HSOD:VBPW:4LIN:BHIL:JDOF
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: bot
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=xhyve
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registry Mirrors:
 http://proxycache.local:5000/
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

The part where it says

```
Registry Mirrors:
 http://proxycache.local:5000/
```

seems to indicate that minikube is setup correctly

If I run `docker pull busybox:latest` it downloads the image, but does not update the mirror. If I pull the catalog `curl http://proxycache.local:5000/v2/_catalog` it is still empty

What else am I missing?

As per the request here is what I get from `docker logs registry-mirror`

```
time="2017-02-20T15:15:34Z" level=warning msg="No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable." go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=f9fc5ef5-0faa-4bdb-b2ef-e5d10d5d5be5 version=v2.5.1 
time="2017-02-20T15:15:34Z" level=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=f9fc5ef5-0faa-4bdb-b2ef-e5d10d5d5be5 version=v2.5.1 
time="2017-02-20T15:15:34Z" level=info msg="Starting upload purge in 50m0s" go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=f9fc5ef5-0faa-4bdb-b2ef-e5d10d5d5be5 version=v2.5.1 
time="2017-02-20T15:15:34Z" level=info msg="using inmemory blob descriptor cache" go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=f9fc5ef5-0faa-4bdb-b2ef-e5d10d5d5be5 version=v2.5.1 
time="2017-02-20T15:15:34Z" level=info msg="Starting cached object TTL expiration scheduler..." go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=f9fc5ef5-0faa-4bdb-b2ef-e5d10d5d5be5 version=v2.5.1 
time="2017-02-20T15:15:34Z" level=info msg="Registry configured as a proxy cache to https://registry-1.docker.io" go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=f9fc5ef5-0faa-4bdb-b2ef-e5d10d5d5be5 version=v2.5.1 
time="2017-02-20T15:15:34Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:5000" go.version=go1.6.3 instance.id=f9fc5ef5-0faa-4bdb-b2ef-e5d10d5d5be5 version=v2.5.1
```

Comment: Is that the full run script you are using?  As in the tutorial it seems to show that you need to use `registry:2 /var/lib/registry/config.yml` after `registry:2`, but you do not seem to have this

Comment: You should also post `docker logs registry-mirror` for the initial startup.  I would be curious that about two cases: 1) Is the link to `config.yml` correct as noted in previous comment and 2) Remove `delete` from the `config.yml` to see if you can get a `HTTP 200` code from the registry

Comment: I removed the delete, nothing changed, however I am questioning if it is even reading my config in the first place. The reason I did not include the config like the tutorial said is because I was including a volume to the original location of the config `-v /Users/proxycache/docker-proxy-cache/config:/etc/docker/registry`. However when I do include the config at the end of the startup script I get an error in docker logs `configuration error: open /Users/proxycache/docker-proxy-cache/config/config.yml: no such file or directory` That file does exist and it has 755 permissions.

Comment: actually I know it is using the config because of the 6th line in docker logs it says "Registry configured as a proxy cache..." and if I remove the volume to the config file that line goes away.

Comment: ok, I got a HTTP 200 by adding a final slash at the end of the curl command `curl -I http://proxycache.local:5000/v2/`

Comment: So it is using your config, and you are getting a `200` response.  Are you able to confirm if it is mirroring the images?  (You can use [`alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/alpine/) if you need a lightweight image)

Comment: no it is not mirroring the images. As before when I run  `docker pull busybox:latest` and then run `curl http://proxycache.local:5000/v2/_catalog` it is empty `{"repositories":[]}`

Comment: What is the result of `cat /etc/default/docker`

Comment: on the docker registry machine everything is commented out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that docker, or coreos does not like the way we setup our DNS. I ended up having to use the ip address of the mirror instead of the DNS name and now it works.